# How to display the Apple logo on the website by Unicode

Tags: css, fonts

Currently I want to display the Apple logo on my website in Unicode. But do not know what to do? We wish everyone help. I already have the Apple logo Unicode code here. But when pasted on the website, it cannot be displayed. Thank you!
My website: https://ktdb.vn

Comment: Can you please share code with your question to show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal Apple logo unicode character, web page, or document portable character for the Apple logo. See
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250058775

There is one that may work on Apple systems, but it’s reserved for private manufacturers use so you may find it showing say a Windows logo.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have understood the problem and I will find out your suggestion.